# ConnectionPool using JDBC connection from Android to Cloud SQL

Tags: android, jdbc, connection-pooling, google-cloud-sql

I've successfully established a connection from my Android app to my Cloud SQL instance (after much trouble).
Establish the connection for each query is unacceptably long and I want to implement a connection pool solution. 
Would anyone have an example of the following:

1. Using the ConnectionPool interface in an android environment?
2. Using any standard managers such as C3P0 in Android (couldn't get it to work as some of the java bean dependencies are not available in the Android environment).

Before you answer please note:
1. I'm new to Java in general so take it easy :)
2. If you're going to suggest using Cloud Endpoints to connect to Cloud SQL, back it up with a WORKING EXAMPLE - I've searched endlessly for an actual example, and this is the only way I got my app to talk to Cloud SQL.

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: In general you shouldn't establish database connections directly from a phone. It is advisable to use a web service for transferring data (and commands) between the phone and the database.

Comment: Thanks Mark. From your suggestion, I'm inferring that I place my raw JDBC connection code in web services? I've done that in past web programming, but according to GAE documentation, Cloud Endpoints is the way to go when it comes to web services on GAE. Of course I have yet to see any Cloud Enpoint implementations for Cloud SQL - thus my current solution.

Comment: Those "cloud endpoints" are webservices, but you will probably need to develop the logic inside the webservice yourself (I don't use google-cloud but that is what I understand from a quick glance at the docs)

Comment: Mark, it seems that the way to do it using cloud endpoints is to do the following: 1. Write a model class for your dB table 2. Generate the endpoint, 3. Rip out the endpoint guts and replace with SQL connection details, 4. Generate client classes. However this seems to me like it's not that much easier than embedding sql code within the app itself, because you still have to manage your connection and write sql queries. If there is a way to generate endpoints that hide the sql connection logic then I would appreciate a small step-by-step